# currently trying to add horizontal scrolling to different sections to an image gallery. Only stacking vertically once reaching window width

Tags: html, css, gallery, horizontal-scrolling

I am currently working on an image gallery where I have different sections that have multiple images. I am currently trying to set up each section of images to be a single row and scoll horizontally similar to what netflix does. Right now I've been unable to get the container to overflow in the x to work and instead goes to a second row.

I've tried using 
white-space: nowrap 
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y:hidden;

display: inline-block;

I've also tried taking a containing div for the list and rotating it 90 deg and allow vertical scrolling and then rotating a child div back.

The best I've been able to get for the effect I'm trying to acheive is the second example but I've been unable to get the width correct on the containing wrapper. I'm trying to get the row all the way across.

First example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>list testing</title>

    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #2e2e2e;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        color: white;
      }

      .galleryContainer {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .gallery {
        width: 90%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
      }

      .sectionWrapper {
        width: 100;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: auto;
      }

      .section {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0.75% 0 0.75% 0;
      }

      ul > .gallery {
        float: left;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: auto;
      }

      ul > li {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;
      }

      li {
        float: left;
        width: 250px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-top: 1%;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
        background-color: #203d68;
        display: inline;
      }

      li:hover {
        filter: grayscale(100%);
        transform: scale(1.1);
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #222222;
        transition: 0.5s ease;
      }

      h2 {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="galleryContainer">
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="sectionWrapper">
          <div class="section">
            <h2>section 1</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>test_1</li>
              <li>test_2</li>
              <li>test_3</li>
              <li>test_4</li>
              <li>test_5</li>
              <li>test_6</li>
              <li>test_1A</li>
              <li>test_2A</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sectionWrapper">
          <div class="section">
            <h2>section 2</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>test_7</li>
              <li>test_8</li>
              <li>test_9</li>
              <li>test_10</li>
              <li>test_11</li>
              <li>test_12</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sectionWrapper">
          <div class="section">
            <h2>section 3</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>test_13</li>
              <li>test_14</li>
              <li>test_15</li>
              <li>test_16</li>
              <li>test_17</li>
              <li>test_18</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Second Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>list testing</title>

    <style>
      body {
        background-color: #2e2e2e;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        color: white;
      }

      .galleryContainer {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .gallery {
        width: 90%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0% 5% 0% 5%;
      }

      .sectionWrapper {
        width: 100;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: auto;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        /* transform-origin: right top; */
      }

      .section {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0.75% 0 0.75% 0;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        /* transform-origin: right top; */
      }

      ul > .gallery {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        display: inline;
      }

      ul > li {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;
      }

      li {
        float: left;
        width: 250px;
        height: 200px;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-top: 1%;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
        background-color: #203d68;
        display: inline;
      }

      li:hover {
        filter: grayscale(100%);
        transform: scale(1.1);
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #222222;
        transition: 0.5s ease;
      }

      h2 {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="galleryContainer">
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="sectionWrapper">
          <div class="section">
            <h2>section 1</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>test_1</li>
              <li>test_2</li>
              <li>test_3</li>
              <li>test_4</li>
              <li>test_5</li>
              <li>test_6</li>
              <li>test_1A</li>
              <li>test_2A</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- <div class="section">
          <h2>section 2</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>test_7</li>
            <li>test_8</li>
            <li>test_9</li>
            <li>test_10</li>
            <li>test_11</li>
            <li>test_12</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="section">
          <h2>section 3</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>test_13</li>
            <li>test_14</li>
            <li>test_15</li>
            <li>test_16</li>
            <li>test_17</li>
            <li>test_18</li>
          </ul>
        </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the second exampe I'm getting the scolling I'm looking to get but not the width. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend you like at `vw` (view width) and `vh` (view height). They work pretty well for scrolling. On Stack Overflow, please try to keep your code brief. We can help a lot better with just the problematic code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a fixed width to your .section wrapper instead of 100%
example: 1000px

Both display:inline-block and float:left will detect if there are spaces beside them so you should set a fixed width container.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I messed with it for the second example that has the rotation to it and added a fix height which is actually the width and it helps a little but the boxes still move to a second row and don't stay on the first row. How would you go about fixing that? Thanks again.